# Adding new devices for iOS testing

Tags: ios, xcode

I sent some testers my .app file and the .mobileprovision file (test devices were added to profile) for ad hoc testing.

Now they have brought on board more testers and have told me to add the new devices to my profile. I went into "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", added the devices and edited the provision profile to include the new devices.

My questions is this: Do I need to go back into my xcode project, add the modified .mobileprovision files, and compile a new .app file or can I just send them the modified .mobileprovision file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a new compile/build a new version of the app.

By the way, if you've never checked it out TestFlight is a fantastic free tool for sending out test builds. It's much better for less technical testers, since once they have given you their device id's, the simply install new app versions by clicking a link in an email, no need to send around provisioning profiles, etc....it also gives you great debug/crash/device/OS data.